# Edit Windows Defender Firewall defaults IPSEC settings through CLI

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-server, ipsec

I am looking for a commandlet to modify the defaults IPSEC settings of the Windows Defender Firewall through CLI. Specifically the defaults authentication settings.

Here is a screenshot of the GUI menu I want to modify : "IPsec defaults"

[Screenshot of the IPsec default window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drDuI.png)

I've been through almost all the Powershell commands starting by "Get-NetFirewall..." or "Get-NetIPsec..." but I don't think any Powershell command allows to do that...

Maybe a netsh command ? Or a registry key ?

Answer (score 0):

try Powershell commands Get-NetIPsecRule Set-NetIPsecRule

[Set-NetIPsecRule on Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-NetIPsecRule)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the deep depths of the [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netipsecphase1authset?view=win10-ps).

The argument **-Default** of the command **New-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet** plays this role of editing the default settings.

As explained in the documentation, an hard-coded GUID is used to specify the default IPSEC authentication settings (lol) :

> **-Default**
>
> Specifies the customized parameters for overriding the defaults for main mode encryption, making it the new default setting for encryption. For the default Phase1Authset object, the default Name parameter value is {E5A5D32A-4BCE-4e4d-B07F-4AB1BA7E5FE3}. To retrieve default settings, query by using the default Name parameter value. To specify a different default cryptographic set, delete the current default set and use the Rename-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet cmdlet to specify the default set with {E5A5D32A-4BCE-4e4d-B07F-4AB1BA7E5FE3}.

Hence, for those looking to edit this settings through Powershell, the solution would be something similar to that :

```powershell
# in case defaults settings would already be present, we remove them...
Remove-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet -Name "{E5A5D32A-4BCE-4e4d-B07F-4AB1BA7E5FE3}"
# and create new default settings
$proposal = New-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet -Anonymous
New-NetIPsecPhase1AuthSet -Default -Proposal $proposal -DisplayName "ServiceHardcoded Default Phase1 AuthSet"
```